# Where to fetch data in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get a feel for reactjs, new to front end development. Google Books API is simple so I decided to use it to build a react page that lists 10 books given the user input.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import './index.css';

const GOOGLE_BOOKS_API = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=';
const GOOGLE_BOOKS_API_LIMIT = 'maxResults=10';

class BookItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
      <img alt="Book" src={this.props.data.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail} />
      <span>{this.props.data.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class BookResults extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const isBookResultsEmpty = !(this.props.books && this.props.books.length > 1);
    const bookItems = isBookResultsEmpty ? [] : this.props.books.map((book,index) =>
      <BookItem key={index} data={book} />
    );
    return (
      <div className='book-results'>
        {isBookResultsEmpty ? (
          <h1>No Results</h1>
        ) : (
          <div> {bookItems} </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class BookSearch extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bookQuery: '',
      books: []
    };
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.getBooks = this.getBooks.bind(this)
  }

  getBooks() {
    let queryString = '';
    if (this.state.bookQuery && this.state.bookQuery.length > 1) {
      queryString = this.state.bookQuery.replace(/\s/g, '+');
      fetch(`${GOOGLE_BOOKS_API}${queryString}&${GOOGLE_BOOKS_API_LIMIT}`)
      .then(results => {
        return results.json();
        })
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          books: json.items
        });
      })
      .catch(e => console.log('error', e));
    }
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      bookQuery: this.search.value
    },
      this.getBooks());
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="book-search">
        <form>
          <input
            placeholder="Search for Books"
            ref={input => this.search = input}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </form>
        <BookResults books={this.state.books} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<BookSearch />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I get an error when typing the input:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'thumbnail' of undefined

I added a check for the data in the BookResults component but the error still occurs. I assume it has to do with the state or props value changing while rendering, but I don't know enough about React to be sure

Comment: I think you just need to check the response JSON. Try logging value of ``this.props.data.volumeInfo`` in console. And check if it is ``imageInfo`` is available in your JSON response.

Comment: As I can see from https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=%27Javascript,maxResults=10, for some books ``imageLinks`` is not available. You need to check if it exists before accessing it's properties. Which is ``thumbnail``.

Comment: Such a simple oversight thank you for catching it! Good to have an extra pair of eyes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some books don't have `imageLinks`, so you need to make sure it is not `undefined` before you use it.

**Example**

```
class BookItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { imageLinks } = this.props.data.volumeInfo;

    if (!imageLinks) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <img alt="Book" src={imageLinks.thumbnail} />
        <span>{imageLinks.thumbnail}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I was able to confirm @Tholle's answer works. Check [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/x2m1rj37vq). here is the [demo image](https://imgur.com/a/8yrH6JT).  I also added `lodash.debounce` to make the query run every 300 milliseconds & changed `onInputChange` to `onKeyUp`. (_Or else you will be flooding Google API_)